# Refactoring Guard Clauses

Tags: c#, validation, guard-clause

What approaches do people take (if any) in managing [guard clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299439/net-guard-class-library) explosion in your classes? For example:

```
public void SomeMethod<T>(string var1, IEnumerable<T> items, int count)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(var1))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("var1");
    }

    if (items == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
    }

    if (count < 1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");
    }

    ... etc ....
}
```

In the project that I am currently working on there are many classes that have a similar set of guard clauses on the public methods.

I am aware of the .NET 4.0 Code Contracts however this is not an option for our team at the moment.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A lot of projects that I've seen use a static `Guard` class.

```
public static class Guard {
    public static void ArgumentIsNotNull(object value, string argument) {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(argument);
    }
}
```

It makes the code a lot cleaner, in my opinion.

```
Guard.ArgumentIsNotNull(arg1, "arg1");
```

Comment: I was just posting the same thing.  The only problem is it puts this method at the top of stack trace vs. the originating method at the top, not that it's all that huge.  This pattern obviously could be used for different types to check a range of values, etc...

Comment: Yeah, that's the only issue I've ever had with it. Although it's easy enough to find the original calling method.

Comment: This is essentially the same thing as the classes that imitate code contracts.

Comment: just used this.  thanks!  First line should be "public static class Guard" not "public static Guard"

Comment: I would suggest you annotate the guard methods with the `[DebuggerHiddenAttribute]`. This ensures that the debugger won't stop in these methods, but return to the original method. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerhiddenattribute.aspx
If you are using ReSharper, you can also annotate the guard methods with the `[ContractAnnotationAttribute]` and the `argument` parameter can be annotated with the `[InvokerParameterName]` giving you intellisense for the parameter name strings.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to go down the Code Contracts route, one way to simplify it is to remove the braces:

```
public void SomeMethod<T>(string var1, IEnumerable<T> items, int count)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(var1))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("var1");

    if (items == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("items");

    if (count < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");

    ... etc ....
}
```

Other than that, there are some ways that you can simulate Code Contracts, if your objection is that .Net 4.0 is not prime time yet:

[http://geekswithblogs.net/Podwysocki/archive/2008/01/22/118770.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20200808072959/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/Podwysocki/archive/2008/01/22/118770.aspx)

Comment: For god's sake, don't do this!  If statements without braces is a great way to cause yourself problems down the road.

Comment: Beware of this! Apple's infamous [goto fail](https://embeddedgurus.com/barr-code/2014/03/apples-gotofail-ssl-security-bug-was-easily-preventable/) was an expensive result of not using braces. (full disclosure: I sometimes do not use braces, but only if the whole thing fits on one line)

Comment: @RufusL: That happened in a programming language infamous for having no safety nets like C# has.  No self-respecting programmer would ever use `goto` in a C# program.

Comment: What safety net are you referring to?

Comment: @RufusL: How many do you want to know about?  Memory management, range protection, exception handling, IL sandboxing... Shall I go on?

Comment: I thought you meant something that would apply to someone adding an extra line after an `if` statement like the goto fail bug, and I couldn't think of any language/compiler feature that would prevent that. Definitely agree with you on not using `goto`.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider refactoring to [Introduce a Null Object](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-null-object).

Answer (score 4):

Meanwhile there's an excellent article about this here: http://haacked.com/archive/2013/01/05/mitigate-the-billion-dollar-mistake-with-aspects.aspx/

I would consider to use [NullGuard.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/NullGuard) as I'm excited about Fodys abilities to reduce boilerplate code

Answer (score 4):

One approach to reducing (not completely removing) number of guard clauses is to understand the cause of their existence. Quite often, it turns that we guard against values that are valid for the type of the argument, but not valid for the method that accepts them. In other words, method is defined on a subset of the domain defined by the argument type.

Solution to this category of cases is to try to define a subtype (e.g. a more restrictive interface) and to accept that type as the argument. You can find an illustrative example in this article: [Why do We Need Guard Clauses?](http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=howto/why-do-we-need-guard-clauses)

Of course, this technique does not apply to all cases. All reference types at least allow null references. Consequently, most of our methods will be defined on part of the domain, which in turn requires a guard clause against null.

But on the positive side, this technique helps grow awareness of methods that receive arguments that are more general than desired. Plumbing that hole helps improve design in general.